# Redraw Scenes Only When the Scene Data Changes

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es

I read this from page on [Tuning Your OpenGL ES App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html) :

> Redraw Scenes Only When the Scene Data Changes :
>   Your app should wait until something in the scene changes before rendering a new frame. Core Animation caches the last image presented to the user and continues to display it until a new frame is presented.
>
> Even when your data changes, it is not necessary to render frames at the speed the hardware processes commands. A slower but fixed frame rate often appears smoother to the user than a fast but variable frame rate. A fixed frame rate of 30 frames per second is sufficient for most animation and helps reduce power consumption.

From what I understand, there is an event loop which keeps on running and re-rendering the scene. We just override the `onDrawFrame` method and put our rendering code there. I don't have any control on when this method gets called. How can then I "*Redraw Scenes Only When the Scene Data Changes*" ?

In my case, there is a change in scene only when user interacts (click, pinch etc.). Ideally I would like to not render when user is not interacting with my scene, but this function is getting called continuously. Am confused.

Comment: Re: "`onDrawFrame`" — that's not supplied by iOS, not part of GLKit, and doesn't follow the usual naming conventions for either Objective-C or Swift. So where is it coming from? That's likely to be from where the answer will come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the lowest exposed level, there is an OpenGL-containing type of CoreAnimation layer, `CAEAGLLayer`. That can supply a colour buffer that is usable to construct a framebuffer object, to which you can draw as and when you wish, presenting as and when you wish. So that's the full extent of the process for OpenGL in iOS: draw when you want, present when you want.

The layer then has a pixel copy of the scene. Normal Core Animation rules apply so you're never autonomously asked to redraw. Full composition, transitions, Core Animation animations, etc, can all occur without any work on your part.

It is fairly common practice to connect up a timer, usually a `CADisplayLink`, either manually or just by taking advantage of one of the `GLKit` constructs. In that case you're trying to produce one frame per timer tick. Apple is suggesting that running the timer at half the refresh rate is acceptable and, if you wake up to perform a draw and realise that you'd just be drawing exactly the same frame as you did last time, not bothering to draw at all. Ideally stopping the timer completely if you have sufficient foresight.

As per the comment, `onDrawFrame` isn't worded like an Objective-C or Swift method and isn't provided by any Apple-supplied library. Whomever is posting that — presumably to try to look familiar to Android authors — needs to take responsibility for appropriate behaviour.